# Android dynamically set ImageView in a list

Tags: android, listview, imageview, simpleadapter

I have a list with the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/outName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/outSurname"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/outAddress"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/outPhone"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/outPhoto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I retrieve my fields from a BD in JSON format using an Async Task, and I fill the list in a onPostExecute function  like so:

```
// Updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                     // Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            MyActivity.this, MyList,
                            R.layout.my_layout, new String[] { “name”, “surname”, “address”, "phone" },
                            new int[] { R.id.outName, R.id.outSurname, R.id.outAddress, R.id.outPhone });
                    // Updating ListView
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });

        }

    }
```

where MyList is an ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> MyList;
MyList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
```

Every field of my results JSONArray is composed by “name”, “surname”, “address”, "phone", and "photo".
"photo" is a numeric field with 4 possible values ( 0, 1, 2, 3 ) where every values refers to specific image I have on a my drawable folder.
How can I set dinamically the image of ImageView depending of this value?

Comment: The `onPostExecute()` is already executed on the UI thread. There is no need to wrap your code in a `runOnUiThread()`. Be aware though that your activity could stopped/destroyed when the `onPostExecute()` is invoked.

Comment: I think it was something like retrieve ImageView by id from R, then call setBackground(drawable) on it. Drawable being a resource you also retrieve via findById from R.

Comment: @LJoosse I have a main class in which I call ( MyClass().execute(); ) another class extends AsyncTask composed by onPreExecute(), doInBackground(String... args) and onPostExecute(String file_url). I always believed it was the best way. Can I do it in a different way?
user3427079 I spent a lot of time thinking a way to do this without an adapter, but I never find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write an adapter. make your own based on this.

```
 public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

        Context context;
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> myList;

        public BankAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> myList){
            this.context = context;
    this.myList=myList;
        }

        static class ViewHolder {
    // Include Number of reqd views.
             private TextView item;
             private ImageView pic;


            }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return items.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int pos) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return items[pos];
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int pos) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String id = items[pos].getId();
            return Long.parseLong(id);
        }


        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ViewHolder mViewHolder = null;
            if(view == null){
                mViewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService
                        (Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listrow,parent,false);
                mViewHolder.item = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.items_txt);
                mViewHolder.pic=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.pics_img)
                view.setTag(mViewHolder);
            }

            else{
                mViewHolder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
            }


            mViewHolder.item.setText(myList.get(position).getKey());
    if(condition){
    //update Image with correct item.
        mViewHolder.pic.setDrawable(//getitemfromList);
    }
            return view;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks, at this point I think that implementing an adapter is the only way to do this.
I write my own adapter, anyway I Can't figure out when I execute my app the list is empty.
This is my adapter: http://pastebin.com/LPf6HRZ2

Comment: Does no matter. I found my own mistake.